# gnome-shell freezing after opening lid/logging in

Tags: gnome, 17.10, gnome-shell, debug, lid

`gnome-shell` freezes almost every time I open the lid of my laptop, and once that happens there's nothing to do but to hard reboot from the power button. It also freezes sometimes after logging in using `gdm3`. I've reported this bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1741839

Is there any workaround for this bug that I can perform to at least reduce its effects, or maybe something I can do when it freezes other than hard rebooting.

Comment: Have you tried removing the **gstreamer-vaapi** package as mentioned in README.md? That solved it for me on Arch.

Comment: It turned out to be a bug in `libinput`. It has been fixed a while ago.

Comment: Bug in libinput, now fixed, so not reproducible